# Posts Uploaded through WooCommerce are not appearing in its category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used Wp-video-post plugin for wordpress woocommerce in which everything is working fine but the posts are not appearing in the category which is selected for that post. Please help.

Comment: Share some screenshot or code or error where you facing the issue.

Comment: So you should contact this plugin authors support pages instead, as in StackOverFlow we don't handle any software support.